# How can I display the area and station name from two tables based in a third table with ID only?

Tags: database, relational-database

I have 4 tables, 3 tables that refers to `area`, `station` and `trainer`. The last one merges the ID from the first 3 tables in order to make the structure easier.
[image]

I would like a query that shows only a determined `area` with the respective `operations` and `trainers` based on the `idArea`, something like this:
[image]

Comment: Welcome César, this seems relatively straightforward. What have you tried so far? Your q mentions `operations`. What table holds them? I suspect the `registers` table isn't there "to make the structure easier". I suspect it's there to tell something like: trainer z works at Station y in Area x.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to the actual question you asked is "natural join".

If you do the natural join between these 4 tables/relations you have, you get a 6-column table/relation : 3 id's and 3 names.

If you project away the 3 id's from that (in SQL, SELECT NAMEAREA, NAMESTATION, NAMETRAINER from that), you get the table/relation you said you were after.

In SQL, doing the natural join can be done using the NATURAL JOIN keyword, or it can be done spelling out the equijin conditions explicitly using ON :

```
SELECT NAMEAREA, NAMESTATION, NAMETRAINER FROM
  REGISTERS NATURAL JOIN AREA NATURAL JOIN STATION NATURAL JOIN TRAINERS
```

or

```
SELECT NAMEAREA, NAMESTATION, NAMETRAINER FROM
  REGISTERS JOIN AREA ON REGISTERS.IDAREA = AREA.IDAREA
            JOIN STATION ON REGISTERS.IDSTATION = STATION.IDSTATION
            JOIN TRAINERS ON REGISTERS.IDTRAINER = TRAINERS.IDTRAINER
```

(Didn't spell-check this on any engine, so perhaps beware of syntax mistakes on my part - still you should be able to advance.)

(Note that in this latter case, the JOINs per se, i.e. without the SELECT, do not yield a 6-column table, but a 9-column one : each id twice, plus the corresponding names.  Meaning the JOINs per se here do not constitute a natural join strictly speaking, but that is irrelevant for the practical purposes you are pursuing.  Just a tiny bit of education about fundamentals worth remembering.)

Answer (score -2):

### Problem

> How can I display the area and station name from two tables?

In a Relational database (noting the tag), that is simple.

> How can I display the area and station name from two tables based in a third table with ID only?

The simple answer is, with `id` on every file, you can't.

The explanation is as follows.

- The *Relational Model* is logical.
- `Record IDs` are physical, anti-relational, 1960's Record Filing Systems. It is what we had before DBMS, and before the advent of the *Relational Model* in 1970. They have none of the Relational Integrity; Relational Power; or Relational Speed of a Relational database.
- Whatever you have read re placing a `Record ID` in a file, is pig poop.
- Eg. You have this problem right here, that Relational databases do not have.
- Beware, such primitive RFS are heavily promoted and marketed as "relational", by the "theoreticians".
- Stamping a `Record ID` on every file (they are files right now, not Relational tables) cripples the data modelling exercise, **as evidenced here, in your question** (and a hundred other questions I have answered).

#### Clarification Requested

In a Relational database, what you are seeking is simple. Correcting your files and elevating them to Relational tables, is easy enough. But first we need some clarifications:

- Don't worry about the `Registers` file right now. At best, it is unresolved, and it will change drastically when Area; Station; and Trainer are clarified.
- It appears a Station belongs to an Area. Fine.
- Then a Trainer belongs to a Station, ***as well as*** to an Area:
- that is not logical
- either a Station (and thence to an Area because a Station belongs to an Area)
  xor an Area, would be fine. But not both
- that would be a simple hierarchic structure.
- If a Trainer indeed belongs to both an Area and a Station, ie. It is not a hierarchic structure, then you need to declare the conditions. Such as, there are Area-Trainers and Station-Trainers, and the conditions for such.

Please clarify, so that the question can be answered.

---

### Comments

<sub>Cézar, you can skip this section.</sub>

> AntC:
> "Stamping a Record ID on every file ..." I see no RecordIDs on any table.

Note that in the question, we notice an `id` on every file. That is a `Record ID`. It can be a `INT, BIGINT, NUMERIC(1), GUID`, etc. It might be named `id, Id, ID, iD`, etc. It is manufactured by the system. It is not from the data. It is properly called a `Record ID` because it is a **physical** pointer to a record, not an Identifier to a **logical** row.

- That is the hallmark of a 1960's Record Filing System. What we had before DBMS, and before the *Relational Model*. That is what is heavily promoted and marketed by the "theoreticians" as "relational".
- The Relational Model is Logical. Keys must be "made up from the data". Surrogates such as `Record IDs` (regardless of what it is named) are specifically prohibited.
- This question seeks a Relational database. Not a primitive filing system.

> I see ids for business-oriented entities.

That is not possible. The question asker has not developed the files yet. There are no "business-oriented entities" in the question. Only four simple files with physical `Record IDs` named `id`.

In any case, if and when we progress to "business-oriented entities", `ids` are 100% redundant, one **additional** column and one **additional** index on every table.